# "Voyage, voyage"

Tags: identify-this-song, history, pop

I was listening this song  with my friends during our trip to Tbilisi (Georgia, USSR) in 1982 (March). (I had a floppy disk brought by a relative from France or Belgium.) I remember this fact exactly but no one believes me.  They say that the song was appeared in 1986. The same one can find in Wikipedia. I don't know how to resolve this contradiction.

Comment: Constructive facts would be helpful, as e. g. the language of the song, man/woman/both/chorus singing. France / Belgium makes French quite likely which would endorse PiedPiper's answer.

Comment: @guidot The Desireless song is the only one of that name released in 1986 and having a Wikipedia page. So we can safely assume that's the one OP is referring to.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are asking about the son "Voyage, Voyage" by Desireless.

The song was sung by Claudie Fritsch-Mentrop under her stage name "Desireless" and composed and produced by Jean-Michel Rivat and Dominique Dubois. She didn't even start working with the composers/producers of the song until 1984. From her [web site](https://www.desireless.net/bio1984-1990):

> En 1984, j'entame ma collaboration avec Jean-Michel Rivat et Dominique Dubois.
>   En 1986, mon baptême Desireless avec la sortie du single : Voyage, Voyage.

The song was originally intended for the singer Michel Delpech, but he [refused to sing it](https://www.lesechos.fr/2016/01/michel-delpech-quand-il-etait-chanteur-194209):

> Lorsque son parolier attitré et ami Jean-Michel Rivat lui propose la chanson « Voyage, voyage », il ne se présente pas au studio, ayant préféré passer le week-end à Rome. Desireless l’enregistre et cela deviendra le classique que l’on connaît.

It looks like your memory is deceiving you. Here's a good article on [false memories](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/False_memory) and how they happen.

Comment: Thank you for a (standard) answer. (It seems that Mister Sherlock Holmes would not be satisfied with it.) But first I will try to find my friends  who were with me in that trip and ask them. Also I will try to ask some my colleagues (of my age) in France .